# Jest moduleNameMapper to change the module everywhere

Tags: jestjs, spfx

When I try to map a module for unit testing with jest to a local file, it says module not found.

For example,

**package.json:**

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "something": "<rootDir>/mockModulesJest/jest/ExtensionStringsModule.js"
},
```

**Somemodule.ts:**

```
import * as a from 'something';
```

It shows module '`something`' not found when I try to run jest.

How do I solve this?
I want to mock some modules from other (my module)file as those modules do ajax calls internally with my implementation.